# How to connect to microk8s API through Python Kubernetes client?

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client, microk8s

I'm trying to connect to my microk8s Kubernetes cluster which is listening on port 16443 with the [Python Kubernetes client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import kubernetes
from kubernetes import client
from kubernetes.client import ApiClient


def setup_cluster():
    configuration = kubernetes.client.configuration.Configuration()
    configuration.host = "https://localhost:16443"
    #configuration.cert_file = "ca.crt"
    #configuration.key_file = "ca.key"
    configuration.api_key["authorization"] = "[the token which I got from kubectl -n kube-system describe secret default-token-abc123]"

    api_client = ApiClient(configuration=configuration)

    v1 = client.CoreV1Api(api_client=api_client)

    print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
    ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
    for i in ret.items:
        print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup_cluster()
```

If I set none of the fields `cert_file`, `key_file` or `api_key` of the configuration in the example, the connection fails due to

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/richter/examples/kubernetes-python/kubernetes-python-port-ignored/kubernetes_python_port_ignored.py", line 26, in <module>
    setup_cluster()
  File "/home/richter/examples/kubernetes-python/kubernetes-python-port-ignored/kubernetes_python_port_ignored.py", line 20, in setup_cluster
    ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
  File "/home/richter/examples/kubernetes-python/kubernetes-python-port-ignored/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/apis/core_v1_api.py", line 13630, in list_pod_for_all_namespaces
    (data) = self.list_pod_for_all_namespaces_with_http_info(**kwargs)
  File "/home/richter/examples/kubernetes-python/kubernetes-python-port-ignored/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/apis/core_v1_api.py", line 13724, in list_pod_for_all_namespaces_with_http_info
    collection_formats=collection_formats)
  File "/home/richter/examples/kubernetes-python/kubernetes-python-port-ignored/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 334, in call_api
    _return_http_data_only, collection_formats, _preload_content, _request_timeout)
  File "/home/richter/examples/kubernetes-python/kubernetes-python-port-ignored/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 168, in __call_api
    _request_timeout=_request_timeout)
  File "/home/richter/examples/kubernetes-python/kubernetes-python-port-ignored/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 355, in request
    headers=headers)
  File "/home/richter/examples/kubernetes-python/kubernetes-python-port-ignored/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 231, in GET
    query_params=query_params)
  File "/home/richter/examples/kubernetes-python/kubernetes-python-port-ignored/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 205, in request
    headers=headers)
  File "/home/richter/examples/kubernetes-python/kubernetes-python-port-ignored/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 68, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "/home/richter/examples/kubernetes-python/kubernetes-python-port-ignored/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 89, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/richter/examples/kubernetes-python/kubernetes-python-port-ignored/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 326, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/home/richter/examples/kubernetes-python/kubernetes-python-port-ignored/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/home/richter/examples/kubernetes-python/kubernetes-python-port-ignored/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/home/richter/examples/kubernetes-python/kubernetes-python-port-ignored/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/home/richter/examples/kubernetes-python/kubernetes-python-port-ignored/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/richter/examples/kubernetes-python/kubernetes-python-port-ignored/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=16443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/pods?watch=False (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))
```

If I specify the `api_key` as shown in the code above I get

```
  File "/home/richter/examples/kubernetes-python/kubernetes-python-port-ignored/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=16443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/pods?watch=False (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))
```

I tried setting some certificates like `ca.crt` and `ca.key` from `/var/snap/microk8s/current/certs` as shown, but this then fails due to

```
  File "/home/richter/examples/kubernetes-python/kubernetes-python-port-ignored/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=16443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/pods?watch=False (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))
```

I'm using microk8s 1.15.0 (695) on Ubuntu 19.04 with Python 3.7 and Kubernetes Python client 10.0.0.

Answer (score 3):

you need to pass path to ca.crt file at `configuration.ssl_ca_cert = 'ca.crt'`.

```
configuration = kubernetes.client.Configuration()
configuration.ssl_ca_cert = 'ca.crt' #<<< look here>>>
configuration.api_key['authorization'] = 'ZXXXXXXXXXXdw=='
configuration.api_key_prefix['authorization'] = 'Bearer'
configuration.host = 'https://aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com'
```

other options are important as well or else you can use default kubeconfig location by adding following line in your code.

```
config.load_kube_config()
```

Generally we can authenticate our client in different ways here i will give example for two ways.

1. By using default location of config file at **~/.kube/config**.

If you are using this method make sure you have, config file at **~/.kube/config**

If there is no file present at this location, use `kubectl config view` to get the content of config file and save it to **config** file and place that file at **~/.kube/config**

**Example for first case:**

*following code will give you listofpods in default namespace*

```
from kubernetes import client, config

#<<<observe below line of code >>>
#uses default config file loccated at ~/.kube/config
config.load_kube_config()

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
for i in ret.items:
    print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))

res = v1.list_namespaced_pod(namespace='default',watch=False)
for i in res.items:
    print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
```

2. By defining certs and bearer token.

**Example for second case**

*This code lists names of namespaces*

```
import kubernetes.client

<<<pay attention here next five lines of code>>>
configuration = kubernetes.client.Configuration()
configuration.ssl_ca_cert = 'ca.crt'
configuration.api_key['authorization'] = 'ZXXXXXXXXXXdw=='
configuration.api_key_prefix['authorization'] = 'Bearer'
configuration.host = 'https://aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com'

api_instance = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api(kubernetes.client.ApiClient(configuration))

api_response = api_instance.list_namespace()
for i in api_response.items:
    print(i.metadata.name)
```

**for more info refer official GitHub repository for examples**

**refer: [my answer to similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158867/having-problem-in-authenticating-kubernetes-python-client)**

Comment: One thing i need to mention is *token* you are using from *default* user may not be sufficient to work with namespaces. create a `seviceaccount` and give him enough permissions using `clusterrolebinding`. Then use this *serviceaccount token* to access namespaces.  @KarlRichter

Answer (score 0):

Your SSL verification is failing the TLS checks. The easiest and quickest fix is to set your Kube config to skip tls-verify because you are using a single node.

```
clusters:
- cluster:  
    server: https://127.0.0.1:16443
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for AWS EKS cluster:

```
import boto3
import kubernetes
import os
import base64

eks = boto3.client('eks')

eks_cluster_name = os.environ['EKS_CLUSTER_NAME']
eks_api_key = os.environ['EKS_API_KEY']

eksresponse = eks.describe_cluster(
    name=eks_cluster_name
)

ca_file = open("/tmp/ca.crt", "wb")
n = ca_file.write(base64.b64decode(eksresponse['cluster']['certificateAuthority']['data']))
ca_file.close()

configuration = kubernetes.client.Configuration()

configuration.ssl_ca_cert = '/tmp/ca.crt'
configuration.api_key['authorization'] = eks_api_key
configuration.api_key_prefix['authorization'] = 'Bearer'
configuration.host = eksresponse['cluster']['endpoint']

api_instance = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api(kubernetes.client.ApiClient(configuration))

api_response = api_instance.list_pod_for_all_namespaces()
for i in api_response.items:
    print(i.metadata.name)
```